# How do I write a JavaScript file that uses jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to JavaScript and JQuery. I know basic C++ and I like including header files and run functions from the header file to keep the code neat.

If I create a new JavaScript file how can I be sure that I can use jQuery in those external JavaScript files?

**Edit:** I have the `jquery.js'. 
**Edit:** My question was terrible. It's taken me a while to see what I originally meant. 
          How do I use Jquery with an external JavaScript file?

Comment: as long as you include jquery...

Comment: maybe you should start here http://docs.jquery.com/

Comment: Should the jquery be included in the head tag or within my demo.js?

Comment: @mcgrailm Okay, then please provide the OP with a link to the manual that he should read. Don't contribute complaints; they aren't really a contribution.

Comment: @mcgrailm Oh. Well, didn't see that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing: move the `jquery.js` file to the same directory in which your HTML file is (or somewhere you know the relative directory to).

In the `<head>` part of your HTML file, add this:

```
<script src = "jquery.js" type = "text/javascript"></script>
```

Again, you might need to change the path in `src` above to the correct one.

Comment: Okay. So I include the jquery file in the head and it should work fine?

Comment: @Drue Precisely. Just make sure your normal JavaScript file is included **after** the jQuery include.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. It's similar to C++ in that aspect.

Comment: I already tried to. I have to wait 3 minutes now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reference jquery from a hosted source or somewhere on your computer using html tags. 
 Take a look at the script tag. I hope it answers your question. You can go to http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:How_jQuery_Works for more tips

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>jQuery demo</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <a href="http://jquery.com/">jQuery</a>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $("a").click(function(event){
     alert("As you can see, the link no longer took you to jquery.com");
     event.preventDefault();
   });
 });
  </script>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Thanks. That's what I was wondering. Include in <head> or in the .js file.

Answer (score 1):

You can include your `jquery.js` within `<head>` tag of your html page as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
```

I assume `js` is the folder to maintain JavaScript files.

Now you can create, you custom functions either in the same HTML within  tags as below:

```
     <script language="javascript">
      $(function(){
            //your function implementation
          });
      </script>
```

Or create a new custom JS file `custom.js`, put your JavaScript functions there and include this file also in the `<head>` as

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js"></script>
```

I hope this helps!